Front Brake Caliper Pistons Jammed
I have a BMW GS310 clocked 30,000 kms the front brakes are not efficient & responsive. upon inspecting the four piston caliper I found that only two pistons are working slightly fine while i apply lever pressure & the rest two are getting struck in middle while protruding out.. whats the main cause for this pistons getting jammed how to sort it out ?
Regards
Skorp

This is mostly a general brake debug process, it won't necessarily explain why you're seeing this imbalanced piston action, but in either case if a piston is not actuating then your brakes are not functioning and need to be fixed. Steps 1-4 can be done by anyone with simple tools and know-how. But as usual when you go out to test your brakes, practice in a wide open area without obstacles and plenty of space to engine brake in case of a faulty system.

First thing to do is bleed your brakes. It could be an air bubble. Old, discolored fluid needs a complete flush. Be sure to use the correct fluid. But look for contaminants. If rust has worked its way into the system, the caliper or piston may be corroded. Brake fluid is hygroscopic, meaning that leaks in the system will draw in water.
Inspect your lines. If the lines are rubber, make sure they're pliable and not kinked or compressed anywhere. Check that banjo bolts are not loose or leaking fluid.
Check the wear on brake pads and discs, if they are way past their wear points the fluid displacement may not be enough to create a good braking pressure. Make sure the caliper and piston are not bent such as from a crash.
Pull the pads off. DO NOT SQUEEZE THE BRAKE LEVER. Visually inspect the pistons. Look for discoloration or wet rubber suggesting that fluid (and air) is bypassing the seals, and try to manually press the nonfunctioning piston inboard to see if it jostles loose. (if contaminants have wedged the piston closed, it is likely to happen again and again without a complete rebuild).
Worst case scenario is the caliper is defective, either broken seals or corrosion, and requires a complete rebuild or replace.

